# GetElementsbyClassName requires more?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so im using one of the javascript bgm player solution that works perfectly in a small website that i created.

basically what i want is duplicating the music controller so that there are two music controls i can place on my website.

the script uses javascript's 'GetElementbyID' attribute in order to identify the div, but In order to get the result i want, i would have to make a slight change to 'GetElementsByClassName' so that there are multiple divs.

but for some reason, it didn't work out as i expected, so i did some stackoverflowing and found out the attribute returning some extra array or something like that,

again, im only a starter ar both javascript and jquery,

and i do not know what i need to add or modify in order to make it work.

can anyone help me out? or is there simpler way to make this work using jquery?

see the script below.

and the live site with the BGM player is here : http://xefrontier.com/

```
if(!window.AudioContext) {
if(!window.webkitAudioContext) {
    alert('no audiocontext found');
}
window.AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext;
}
var context;
var audioBuffer;
var sourceNode;
var analyser;
var javascriptNode;
var ctx = jQuery("#canvas").get()[0].getContext("2d");
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
gradient.addColorStop(0, '#FFFFFF');
gradient.addColorStop(0.50, '#00D4CD');
gradient.addColorStop(0.65, '#FF00CC');
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#1A1A1A');
var currentlyPlaying = 0;
var playing = false;
var trackList = [{
title: "Back For You",
artist: "One Direction",
filename: "bg2.mp3"
}, {
title: "Does He Know",
artist: "One Direction",
filename: "bg3.mp3"
}];
var playbackButton = document.getElementBy("playback-button");
playbackButton.onclick = togglePlayState;
var playIconClass = "fontawesome-play";
var pauseIconClass = "fontawesome-pause";
var nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button");
nextButton.onclick = nextTrack;
var prevButton = document.getElementById("prev-button");
prevButton.onclick = prevTrack;
var playbackIcon = document.getElementById("playback-icon");

function togglePlayState() {
if(!playing) {
    startPlayback(currentlyPlaying);
    return;
}
switch(context.state) {
    case 'running':
        playbackIcon.className = playIconClass;
        context.suspend();
        break;
    case 'suspended':
        playbackIcon.className = pauseIconClass;
        context.resume();
        break;
}
}

function displayPlaying() {
var trackInfoElement = document.getElementById("trackInfo");
trackInfoElement.innerHTML = trackList[currentlyPlaying]['title'] + " - " + trackList[currentlyPlaying]['artist'];
}

function displayPlaylist() {
var playlist = document.getElementById('playlist');
playlist.innerHTML = "";
for(var i = currentlyPlaying; i < trackList.length; i++) {
    var track = document.createElement('li');
    if(i === currentlyPlaying) track.class = "playing";
    track.innerHTML = trackList[i]['title'] + ' - ' + trackList[i]['artist'];
    playlist.appendChild(track);
    }
}

function startPlayback(trackID) {
displayPlaylist()
if(playing) {
    stopPlayback();
}
context = new AudioContext()
setupAudioNodes();
loadSound("/xe/" + trackList[trackID]['filename']);
playing = true;
playbackIcon.className = pauseIconClass;
}

function stopPlayback() {
context.close();
playing = false;
playbackIcon.className = playIconClass;
}

function nextTrack() {
if(currentlyPlaying === trackList.length - 1) currentlyPlaying = 0;
else currentlyPlaying += 1;
startPlayback(currentlyPlaying);
}

function prevTrack() {
if(currentlyPlaying === 0) currentlyPlaying = trackList.length - 1;
else currentlyPlaying -= 1;
startPlayback(currentlyPlaying);
}

function setupAudioNodes() {
javascriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
javascriptNode.connect(context.destination);
javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {
    var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 2000, 1000);
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    drawSpectrum(array);
}
analyser = context.createAnalyser();
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
analyser.fftSize = 512;
sourceNode = context.createBufferSource();
sourceNode.onended = function() {
    nextTrack();
}
sourceNode.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(javascriptNode);
sourceNode.connect(context.destination);
}

function loadSound(url) {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
        playSound(buffer);
    }, onError);
}
request.send();
}

function playSound(buffer) {
sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
sourceNode.start(0);
}

function onError(e) {
console.log(e);
}

function drawSpectrum(array) {
for(var i = 0; i < (array.length); i++) {
    var value = array[i];
    ctx.fillRect(i * 8, 350 - value, 2, 50);
}
};
```

Comment: don't just throw the whole script at us, where is you cloning button function?

Comment: sorry, i posted the original script. i basically changed all the getElementByID to getElementsbyClassName.

Comment: you realize that getElementByID and getElementsbyClassName do different things wright?

Comment: i just found that out @madalinivascu. the purpose of this question is for the illumination, and possibly the solution.

Comment: getElementsbyClassName  gets the element by class the other by id if your code has each element a class and a id with the same value then this code should word, if not you need to change the id's to classes

Comment: @madalin ivascu so, does it work if i put it like this : var playbackIcon = jQuery('.playback-icon.) instead of var playbackIcon = document.getElementById("playback-icon");?

Comment: NO lol with jquery you are selecting based on the class with plain javascript you are selecting by id